# Can a utility method return raw html in MVC razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, razor

I am trying to output a value to the page using MVC razor of autoplay='autoplay' in order to autoplay HTML5 video. My method GetAutoPlayVideo reads the web.config file to determine if the site will autoplay the videos.

```
public static string GetAutoPlayVideo()
{
     bool autoPlayVideo = Converter.ToBoolean(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AutoPlayVideo"]);
     if (autoPlayVideo)
     return "autoplay='autoplay'";
     else
         return string.Empty;
}
```

Then on the page use the following markup:

```
    <div id="videoHolder">
                <video id="video" width="503" height="284" @Html.Raw(MyUtility.GetAutoPlayVideo()) controls >
                @foreach (string s in Model.SelectedShow.VideoFiles)
                {
                    <source src="@(CdnResources.GetImageUrl(s))" type="@(Utility.GetMimeType(s))" />
                }
                Your browser does not support the video tag.
            </video>
        </div>
```

The syntax I have created so far is this:

```
@Html.Raw(MyUtility.GetAutoPlayVideo())
```

is it possible to shorten this up to something like?

```
@MyUtility.GetAutoPlayVideo()
```

Comment: This might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707518/razor-and-html-helpers

Comment: It is important to remember that HTML helpers are not magic; they are ordinary C# (extension) methods.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes.

The Razor escaping system will not escape anything of type `IHtmlString`.  The `Html.Raw()` method simply returns an `HtmlString` instance containing your text.

You can simply declare your method as returning `IHtmlString`, and call `Html.Raw()` (or `new HtmlString()` inside.

Comment: I tried that but my utility method did not understand Html.Raw(). Could you tell me how to declare it?

Comment: @Orin: If you don't have an `HtmlHelper` instance, you'll need to create an `HtmlString` yourself.