# MVC does not provide HTML helpers for basic elements

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

Is there any reason why MVC does not come up with HTML helpers for all the basic elements, for example img, button etc.

I know that we can write our own HTML extension to build the tag, But what is the reason for not covering all the basic elements by default.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why should they? :-) You can write an image tag just as easily and use their `UrlHelper`s to get the content urls? Also, you can create your own: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707518/razor-and-html-helpers

Comment: The html helpers primarily bind to model properties. Not much call for binding a property to a button.

Comment: @janhartmann I am aware that we can write our own helpers. If you say that its easy to write your own tags, how difficult would it be to write a lable tag not a button.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is it wouldn't be useful. Would you want all combinations of possible attributes? Or possibility to just add whatever attributes you want? How complicated do you want it to be?

It would only take unnecessary CPU time and the developer would have to write a lot more code to output something they already know they're outputting.

It would be different, if there would be, for example, several different types of images and there would be a need for some logic. But since every image is just the same in HTML, it would be pointless.

Lazy coders are good coders, and most would definitely write `<img src="@bindings" alt="@something" />` than some `@Html.Image(src=bindings, alt=something)` that wouldn even hide the simple output.

Comment: I'm not sure that I quite understand your point here.  I'm not sure that this is the reason that there are Html helpers for some form elements and not the button.  I think I agree with @Stephen Muecke's comment more, that it is to do with model binding the view passed through from the controller.